# Different color for single bars in a chart with multiple bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am currently trying to format my data in a bar chart. Here I want the bars for the first stage to be differently colored than the other ones in the same figure. I tried to achieve this using 4 different plots and setting the values in the other charts to 0 but now there obviously are these gaps where the other charts should be. Below the image is my current code. Is there any way to just change the color of the bars for stage 1 without creating the invisible bars for the other stages? Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5}, xtick=data, xbar = .1cm, x = 2cm, ylabel = {Times chosen}, ymajorgrids = true, ymin=0, xtick style={draw=none}]
            \addplot[ybar, fill=green] coordinates {
            (Stage 1, 69)
            (Stage 2, 0)
            (Stage 3, 0)
            (Stage 4, 0)
            (Stage 5, 0)
            };
            \addplot[ybar, fill=orange] coordinates {
            (Stage 1, 231)
            (Stage 2, 0)
            (Stage 3, 0)
            (Stage 4, 0)
            (Stage 5, 0)
            };
            \addplot[ybar, fill=blue] coordinates {
            (Stage 1, 0)
            (Stage 2, 84)
            (Stage 3, 234)
            (Stage 4, 111)
            (Stage 5, 198)
            };
            \addplot[ybar, fill=red] coordinates {
            (Stage 1, 0)
            (Stage 2, 216)
            (Stage 3, 57)
            (Stage 4, 189)
            (Stage 5, 102)
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:amt_result}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic x coords={Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5},
xtick=data,
xbar=0.1cm,
x=2cm,
ylabel={Times chosen},
ymajorgrids=true,
ymin=0,
xtick style={draw=none},
]
\addplot[ybar, fill=green, forget plot, bar shift=-0.5*(\pgfplotbarwidth+0.1cm)] coordinates {
(Stage 1, 69)
};
\addplot[ybar, fill=orange, forget plot, bar shift=0.5*(\pgfplotbarwidth+0.1cm)] coordinates {
(Stage 1, 231)
};
\addplot[ybar, fill=blue] coordinates {
(Stage 2, 84)
(Stage 3, 234)
(Stage 4, 111)
(Stage 5, 198)
};
\addplot[ybar, fill=red] coordinates {
(Stage 2, 216)
(Stage 3, 57)
(Stage 4, 189)
(Stage 5, 102)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar chart with different colored bars]